# ASP .Net Web App not publishing .cs files and Database

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a web portal app. I built it in Asp .Net. The app is now ready but when I try to publish it using Visual Studio, I only get the .aspx and .css files. It does not include the .cs files that have all the backend code and functionality, and it does not include the database either. The method I used for publishing the app was:
Right Click my project -> Click on Publish -> Select IIS,FTP,etc -> Select File System and provide Target Path -> Click Save. 
It published the app at that targeted location. But, when I open that folder, I can only see the .aspx and .css files and no .cs files, as you can see in the following screenshot.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15pecp8tbamjlWCm4rfV6M_zeW7zdUUB9/view?usp=sharing

At first, I thought maybe this is how it publishes the app, as this is the first time that I have tried to publish a web app. Therefore, I loaded it to IIS as it is, and tried to browse it. When I browse it, it loads the first page, that is a login page, correctly. But when I enter user credentials and try to login, it provides me with following error:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TIC0gE1tFpcne4bXaSsEVm8yiOPnIyOt/view?usp=sharing

I have underlined the lines by which I got the idea that the error is related to database and .cs files.

Please, if anyone can help me about this, it will be really appreciated. I have a deadline and I dont have any idea that how can I solve this problem. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish your web application the visual studio compiles all your your cs/vb/class code into binary files (dll), this dll files can be found in your site bin folder, so you can't find the .cs file.

There are many causes of the network path was not found which are given:
1.Antivirus 2.Firewall 3.SQL Server Network configuration.
and please check if you have the port in the connection string "Data Source=x.x.x.x,1433".
More information about this error you can refer to this video:[Resolving SQL Server Connection Errors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1k00z82u4OI)

Comment: Hy, thanks for your reply. I have some other projects that are already running on the office network and they are also hosted on IIS. But only this one is giving this error. I think if I change the config settings, it might give errors in other projects.

Comment: This error is caused by your database being unable to connect correctly, you only need to try to modify the configuration of the database connection.

Comment: Yeah, your answer worked. I was giving my PC name as the data source in the connection string. When I gave the server name as data source, it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a web application your .cs files are compiled into a DLL which will be in the `bin` folder.

The special `App_Code` folder can be created and the .cs files in there will no be compiled during publish and will be compiled by IIS on demand.